# Traversing integer spiral in a different direction

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

Arrange the positive integers in a counter-clockwise spiral (often referred to as Ulam's spiral), beginning with `1` and starting out east, north:

```
17--16-15-14-13
|            | 
18  5--4--3  12
|   |     |  | 
19  6  1->2  11
|   |        | 
20  7--8--9--10
|              
21-22-23-24--25
```

Is there a function that would produce the integers for each step on the same grid -- but starting out going *west-south*, like this?:

```
17--16-15-14-13
             | 
18--5--4--3  12
|         |  | 
19  6<-1  2  11
|   |     |  | 
20  7--8--9  10
|            |
21-22-23-24--25
```

That is, I'm trying to create a function `f(n) -> a` where `n` is the "step" and `a` is the integer located at that spot. Sample results would be:

```
n -> a
-----
0 -> 1
1 -> 6
2 -> 7
3 -> 8
4 -> 9
5 -> 2
6 -> 3
7 -> 4
8 -> 5
... ...
```

Is there such a function?

---

I've been tinkering with this for a couple of hours and here's what I've observed so far. (I'm excluding `0` from what follows since it seems to be an exception.)

This sequence is made up of "segments" that increase incrementally but "jump down" after the square of an odd number, and then "jump up". The length of each "segment" is divisible by `4`, and that length increases by `4` every two segments.

```
6-7-8-9 | 2-3-4-5  (length: 4)
18-19-20-21-22-23-24-25 | 10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17  (length: 8)
38-39-40-41-42-43-44-45-46-47-48-49 | (length: 12) ... [etc!]
```

The difference between `n` (the "step") and `a` (the integer at that position) looks like it's always odd.

```
+5, -3, +9, -7, +13, -11, ...
```

---

So I've found some useful patterns here, but haven't yet figured out a way to synthesize them into one function. If there's a known formula, I would accept that as an answer, but I am game to keep trying to solve this myself if anyone has a useful clue. I'm an amateur, so my apologies if I haven't stated this question using the right terminology.

Comment: No extra information, but the sequence is in OEIS: http://oeis.org/A090928

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally cracked this. I would really appreciate a review, or thoughts on ways to simplify this, since I took what feels like a convoluted route to get there.

We need a function $F(x) \to n$, where argument $x$ is the "step" and the result $n$ is the integer we're standing on at that step.

Observations:

1. The sequence forms a kind of meta-piecewise function.
2. Within each segment, the sequence increases incrementally.
3. The interval size of each segment increases by $4$ every $2$ segments.
4. At each segment, $n - x$ jumps to the next term in $1,5,-3,9,-7,13,-11,17,-15...$

I broke the problem down into:

---

$H(x)=\bigl\lceil{\sqrt{x+1}}\bigr\rceil-\bigl\lceil{\sqrt{x+1}}\bigr\rceil\bmod2 \quad\textit{Nearest even number}\le x$

$I(x)=\bigl(H(x)\div2\bigr)\cdot{4} \quad\textit{Interval size of the segment containing}\ x$

$J(x)=\bigl(H(x)+1\bigr)^2-I(x) \quad\textit{Nearest odd square}\ge x\ \textit{("southeast spoke")}$

$L(x)=\bigl(\lfloor{x}\div{J(x)}\rfloor-1\bigr)^2-\lfloor{x}\div{J(x)}\rfloor \quad\textit{Diff. betw. interval size and nearest odd}$

$M(x)=\bigl(L(x)+I(x)\bigr)\cdot{L(x)}\quad\textit{Diff. betw. step x and integer n}$

Which, put together, gives the function we want:

$F(x)=x+M(x)$

---

In code (*written for parity with the above; not optimized*) this might look like:

```
function G(x){ return Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(x + 1)); }
function H(x){ return G(x) - (G(x) % 2); }
function I(x){ return (H(x) / 2) * 4; }
function J(x){ return Math.pow(H(x) + 1, 2) - I(x); }
function K(x){ return Math.floor(x / J(x)); }
function L(x){ return Math.pow(K(x) - 1, 2) - K(x); }
function M(x){ return (L(x) + I(x)) * L(x); }
function F(x){ return x + M(x); }
```

Which can be checked with:

```
var terms = [
  1,
  6,  7,  8,  9,
  2,  3,  4,  5,
  18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,
  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17,
  38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49,
  26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37
];

for (var i = 0; i < terms.length; i++) {
  var step = i;
  var term = terms[i];
  console.log(step, '->', F(step), F(step) === term);
}
```

---

And here's a table of the results for each function for the first several steps:

```
x     0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
G(x)  1   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   3
H(x)  0   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
I(x)  0   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
J(x)  1   5   5   5   5   5   5   5   5
K(x)  0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
L(x)  1   1   1   1   1  -1  -1  -1  -1
M(x)  1   5   5   5   5  -3  -3  -3  -3
n     1   6   7   8   9   2   3   4   5
```

And the same in a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ahz_ZQm7pkwTdEJiNG1CRXdKTi1WT29TTGQ4T2d0dnc#gid=0).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the work in the other answer, we can compact this into two functions:

```
F:  x+((pow(K-1,2)-K)+2*(2*floor(ceil(sqrt(x+1))/2)))*(pow(K-1,2)-K)
```

$
 F(x) = \big((K-1)^2 - K\big)\bigg(4 \big\lfloor \frac{\lceil \ \sqrt{x+1}\ \ \rceil}{2}\big\rfloor + (K-1)^2 - K \bigg) + x
$

Where $K$ is given by:

```
K:  floor(x/((pow(2*floor(ceil(sqrt(x+1))/2),2))+1))
```

$
K(x) =\bigg\lfloor x \div \bigg(4 \big\lfloor \frac{\lceil \ \sqrt{x+1}\ \ \rceil}{2} \big\rfloor ^2 + 1 \bigg) \bigg\rfloor
$

---

And in code a nicer function might be:

```
function F2(x) {
  var q = 2*floor(ceil(sqrt(x+1))/2);
  var r = floor(x/((pow(q,2))+1));
  var s = pow(r-1,2)-r;
  return x+(s+2*q)*s;
}
```

Another code variant:

```
function F3(x) {
  var p = floor(ceil(sqrt(x+1))/2);
  var r = floor(x/(4*pow(p,2)+1));
  var s = pow(r,2)-3*r+1;
  return 4*p*s+pow(s,2)+x;
}
```